# Find the start time and End time when temperature is changed 1degree in spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We have columns ID, TIME, Temperature in table need to Identify exact 1degree change in temperature and their start and end time, we are getting reading for every one minute but few times readings might not be present. This would be a time series data

```
    ID , TimeStamp  , Temp(F)
    1, 2019-12-20 10:08:35 74.1
    2, 2019-12-20 10:08:40 74.3
    1, 2019-12-20 10:09:37 73.7
    2, 2019-12-20 10:09:40 74.2
    3, 2019-12-20 10:09:40 74.0
    1, 2019-12-20 10:10:32 73.5
    1, 2019-12-20 10:12:02 73.0
    2, 2019-12-20 10:12:40 73.3
    1, 2019-12-20 10:13:35 73.3
    2, 2019-12-20 10:13:40 73.1
    1, 2019-12-20 10:14:37 73.0
    2, 2019-12-20 10:14:40 72.9
    3, 2019-12-20 10:15:42 72.7
    1, 2019-12-20 10:15:43 72.7
    1, 2019-12-20 10:16:47 72.4
    2, 2019-12-20 10:16:40 72.5
    1, 2019-12-20 10:17:57 72.0
    2, 2019-12-20 10:17:40 72.3
    1, 2019-12-20 10:18:47 72.0
    2, 2019-12-20 10:18:40 72.0
    1, 2019-12-20 10:19:50 72.4
    2, 2019-12-20 10:19:50 72.3
    1, 2019-12-20 10:20:51 72.7
    2, 2019-12-20 10:20:50 72.8
    1, 2019-12-20 10:21:53 72.7
    2, 2019-12-20 10:22:50 73.0
    1, 2019-12-20 10:23:53 73.0
    2, 2019-12-20 10:23:50 72.9
    1, 2019-12-20 10:23:57 73.1
    2, 2019-12-20 10:23:56 72.7
```

In the above data set I would need only when temperature is reduced 1 degree and their start time and end time preferably with out UDF's currently my framework not capable of handling UDF's.

End Result would be when Temperature difference is exactly 1 degree change when it is continuously decreasing.

```
    ID,     Start Time,           End Time, 
    2, 2019-12-20 10:08:40   2019-12-20 10:12:40
    1, 2019-12-20 10:09:37   2019-12-20 10:15:43
```

*Note: for ID 2 we have temperature difference 1 degree in between 2019-12-20 10:12:40 and 2019-12-20 10:17:40 but in this period temperature was decreased and then raised so this record shouldn't appear in result.

How can I achieve this with SQL? Is it possible to get in SQL alone?

Comment: for ID-1 from 2019-12-20 10:09:37 to 2019-12-20 10:15:43, the Temp changed: 73.7 -> 73.5 -> 73.0 -> 73.3 -> 73.0 -> 72.7, which does not match your requirements. but ID-2 between 2019-12-20 10:12:40 and 2019-12-20 10:17:40 does match. can you clarify this?